# After flyway migration spring data not counting rows for SERIAL column

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, flyway

I have migrations that work fine but after migration successfully created in DB and test data loaded I get the error on creating operation.

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"
>   Detail: Key (id)=(1) already exists.

Query from SQL spring data log:

> insert into users (account_non_expired, account_non_locked,
>   credentials_non_expired, enabled, password, username) values (?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?)

In migration, I setting a couple of test users into the table but hibernate not notice it and trying write row as a first.

My `users` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
(
    id                      BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    username                VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password                VARCHAR(255)        NOT NULL,
    account_non_expired     BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
    account_non_locked      BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
    credentials_non_expired BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
    enabled                 BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE
);
```

Entity class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "roles")
@ToString(exclude = "roles")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "account_non_expired")
    private Boolean accountNonExpired;

    @Column(name = "account_non_locked")
    private Boolean accountNonLocked;

    @Column(name = "credentials_non_expired")
    private Boolean credentialsNonExpired;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private Boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Role> roles;
}
```

Actually strategy `GenerationType.IDENTITY` work with `BIGSERIAL` when I send requests 3 times after increment stay in the right place. With each request to DB Hibernate make +1.

This users data migration:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, username, password)
VALUES (1, 'user', 'pass'),
       (2, 'operator', 'pass'),
       (3, 'admin', 'pass');
```

How to fix it for Hibernate can notice the amount of data the data from start?

Comment: A bigserial column is backed by a sequence: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL. Since you insert values in your flyway migration without getting the IDs from this sequence, the next value from the sequence stays where it is. And so when Hibernate inserts a value by letting the database generate an ID, the sequence gives an ID that is already used. So you need to set the value of the sequence after you've inserted data in it. Look for setval in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createsequence.html

Comment: @JB Nizet it's mean if I get rid of setting directly ID in migration. Does it solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to migration `SELECT setval('users_id_seq', 4);`

```
INSERT INTO users (id, username, password)
VALUES (1, 'user', 'pass'),
       (2, 'operator', 'pass'),
       (3, 'admin', 'pass');

SELECT setval('users_id_seq', 4);
```

This resolves a conflict between a state of the sequence and the real amount of rows.

Comment: It works for the database initialization, but I think it is not a viable solution when the app "lives" in production. So, any idea to retrieve then update the actual sequence before inserting data ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a sequence for your id :

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USER_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "USER_SEQ", sequenceName = "USER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
```

Create your SQL file like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO users (id, username, password)
VALUES (NEXTVAL('USER_SEQ'), 'user', 'pass'),
       (NEXTVAL('USER_SEQ'), 'operator', 'pass'),
       (NEXTVAL('USER_SEQ'), 'admin', 'pass');
```

The sequence for the table "users" should be automatically updated.